# How do I do something if an Optional<String> is not present or present but an empty string?

Tags: java, option-type

I can't seem to figure out a more concise way to do this

```
Optional<String> foo;
if (!foo.isPresent() || StringUtils.isBlank(foo.get())) {
  // ...
}
```

There's this but it actually makes the logic more convoluted, IMO:

```
Optional<String> foo;
if (!foo.filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank).isPresent()) {
  // ...
}
```

Feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: What does your question mean? Do you want to check if a String is null or not? Describe why do you need to use Optional.

Comment: The filter statement seems fine to me.

Comment: I need to throw an exception UNLESS the string is present and non-blank. Just finding it weird that I can't find a non-conjunctive, non-convoluted "wording".

Comment: Really depends on what you need to do in the block. Does it require mutating the out-scoped variables? If you're just looking to replace the empty you can use `foo.filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank).orElseGet(() -> ...)`

Comment: @AndrewCheong see my answer.

Comment: if you do not need the `Optional`, that is, you got just a `String`: `if (string.isBlank()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();` will throw NPE if the string is `null`, and IAE if blank (but I would prefer explicit testing for `null`)

Comment: @AndrewCheong *if its present*, would you do a different operation as well? or else could you update the question accordingly for `if` and `else` branches.

Comment: @nullpointer - In my case, no. The code just continues without exception if present and non-blank. I think I'd like to keep the code as-is because as an inexperienced Java developer it was what made sense to me, and I figure what others in my boat will be looking for too.

Comment: @flakes - I see now you were on the right path but I just didn't really understand a few hours ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for.

```
Optional.of("")
        .filter(not(String::isBlank)))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new MyException("..."));
```

You'll find `not` under `Predicate`.

Obviosuly this is less efficient than having an `if` statement, but it has its place.

Ah, ok, after your comment it is more clear. Use `orElseThrow`.

Comment: I think your answer is more readable than mine, especially because OP clarified that his goal is to throw an exception.

Comment: @JacobG. your answer was the right one before his clarification.

Comment: and worth mentioning this is Java 11 for `Predicate.not` and `String.isBlank`

Answer (score 3):

With Java 11, you can use `Predicate#not`, `Optional#isEmpty`, and `String#isBlank` to be more concise:

```
Optional<String> foo = ...;

if (foo.filter(not(String::isBlank)).isEmpty()) {
    // ...
}
```

The if-statement body will only be entered if `foo` is already empty or the `String` that `foo` contains is the empty `String`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Optional#orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) to sub in an empty string if the string doesn’t exist, then use `StringUtils.isBlank()` on the result:

```
Optional<String> foo;

if (StringUtils.isBlank(foo.orElse(""))) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I may actually go with this answer because the style in the repo doesn't really use `orElseThrow`s or `not()` (and actually we're still not upgraded to Java 11) so your answer is the most readable. Thanks!